# Работа с Node.js

Tags: node.js, jquery, javascript

Что за штука node.js, насколько она полезна, какие задачи лучше организовывать именно node'ом? Ставится ли она на winxpsp3, как сделать hello world?

Comment: btw,
> Учиться хакерству на машинах, работающих под DOS, Windows или MacOS - это все равно что учиться танцевать, будучи полностью загипсованным.
>
> Если вы задаёте этот вопрос, это наверняка значит, что вы думаете о том, чтобы заниматься хакерством под Windows. Это является само по себе плохой идеей. Когда я сравнил попытки хакать под Windows с попыткой танцевать в гипсе, я не прикалывался. Не пытайтесь идти этой дорогой. Она ужасна, и никогда не перестанет быть такой
esr, "How to become a hacker"

Comment: у меня и в мыслях такого не было, я не знаю почему вы так решили, я не собираюсь ничего хакать, просто мне как программисту интересно что это за штука, а вы изв. "наваляли".

Comment: хакать и хакер, в старом смысле. не о взломщиках

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Основная направленность сервера - работа с приложениями, требующими частых пересылок небольших количеств информации (а ля Comet) наподобие чатов, игр и т.п.

Node.js работает на Windows XP, начиная, как минимум, с SP 2. Официальных упоминаний не встречалось, но люди, использующие сервер, подтверждают это. Например здесь - [Porting Node to Windows With Microsoft’s Help](http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/06/23/porting-node-to-windows-with-microsoft%E2%80%99s-help/):

> Supported Platforms:
>
> Microsoft Windows operating systems since Windows XP sp2. It can be built
> with either Visual Studio or MinGW.

Довольно любопытные обзоры:

- [Node.js — руководство по убеждению начальства](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/nodejs/118310/)
- [Полезные инструменты, туториалы и ресурсы](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/nodejs/128601/)

Comment: "небольших количеств информации"???

WTF, кто мешает пересылать тонны информации используя подход стриминга? Не вводите людей в заблуждение, не даром, на node делают загрузку файлов на сервер, перекодировщики видео потоков и т.д.

Хотя конечно да - это не на php забыдлокодить, в плане скорости разработки немного дольше, ну и для большинства, скорее всего - unreal

Хотя, опять таки - модули в помощь, все-равно это не проблема.

Comment: Ну и забыл добавить - в основу node заложена скорость, асинхронность и расширяемость.

С помощью ноды можно получить великолепный показатель RPS на довольно скромном железе.

К тому-же, нередко, на Node переписывают высоко-нагруженные либо особо требовательные к ресурсам участки кода.

Answer (score 3):

Хелловорд прямо на главной [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/)  :)

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

Comment: код я меньше всего хотел увидеть, зачем он вообще нужен, откуда взялся и что с ним делать? Пока что по моим скромным знаниям для меня node.js это такая штука, не знаю как даже назвать, язык что ли, хотя нет, больше библиотека, или фреймворк js или расширение, которое выполняет javascript на стороне сервера, а не на стороне клиента или я не прав?

Comment: На главной странице по шагам расписано, что и как делать с кодом. Конкретно надо его просто запустить (предположим, это файл hello.js):

    node hello.js

Comment: да, потом пойти на http://127.0.0.1:1337/ и увидеть "Hello world"

Comment: в названии node.js приставка ".js" скорее для красоты, как .NET у MS. Это приложение, которое на стороне сервера выполняет javascript-код, который формирует html-странички, попадающие к клиентам.

Comment: @Tolbase - на node можно сделать все тоже что и, например, на php.
Знания у вас не скромные, скромные это когда они есть, у вас же их нет, иначе такой глупости вы бы не писали.

Comment: те, у кого их(знаний о node.js, хотя бы о его существовании) нет , те вообще не спрашивают, мне по крайней мере интересно что за зверь.

Comment: @Tolbase - читните мои комменты чуть выше. И если вам действительно интересно посмотрите хотя-бы выступления Раяна на ютубе и **обязательным образом** - [это](http://ontwik.com/javascript/douglas-crockford-serversideness/)

Еще раз повторюсь если у вас нет чего-либо из перечисленого - забудьте, только зря потратите время: знание и приязненное отношение к javascript, готовность изучения чего-то в корне нового, готовность учиться и использовать ноду (иначе - нафига она вам нужна*???)

Comment: Чуть не забыл - без знания английского можете и не браться

Answer (score 3):

[Очень хорошая статья про сравнение ерланга и нод](http://fprog.ru/2010/issue6/dmitry-demeshchuk-node.js-vs-erlang/)
Если в кратце, то нод - это однопоточный неблокирующий веб-сервер, использующий javasript.

1. Однопоточный, означает, что ни физических ни виртуальных параллельных процессов нод не использует, из-за этого упрощается работа с общими данными, но усложняется масштабирование на многопроцессорных машинах
2. Неблокирующий означает, что все блокирующие операции (такие как запись/чтение из файла например) заменяются колбэками - обратными вызовами, и нод в это время может заняться другими вычислениями
3. Javascript позваляет использовать только один язык для написания и клиентской части и серверной

Comment: "усложняется масштабирование на многопроцессорных машинах"

О да, написать обвертку для нескольких дочерних потоков и запустить 2 или больше серверов - это "очень сложно", кстати, для тех кто в танке - это решает проблему много ядерных процессоров, масштабирование как раз таки один из самых ярких плюсов ноды, причем как вертикально так и горизонтально, не несите ерунды.

Забыли упомянуть о низком потреблении ресурсов сервера при высокой производительности.

И еще, как бы там не думал Раян, писать на nodejs правильно довольно сложно.

Comment: Вы не поняли. У Erlang/OTP масштабирование на уровне микропроцессов (в сыром виде — `spawn_link/4`, в реальности — `plists:map(fun my_fun/1, MyList)` и вычисление радостно разлетелось по кластеру), а у node.js — на уровне процессов системы «а теперь запустим вторую копию и нагрузим еще вот это ядро» с load-balancer'ом спереди. На фоне distributed Erlang/OTP у Node.js масштабирование, на самом деле, смотрится довольно примитивно.

Answer (score 0):

Для запуска веб-сервера с Node.js на Windows для целей разработки рекомендую взглянуть на [Winginx](http://winginx.ru/). В нем уже есть настроенный Node.js и проксирующий nginx для гибкой работы сервера, включая работу с несколькими проектами.